# SQLAlchemy: Class values not populated in SQLite table after converting csv to dictionaries

Tags: sql, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I created a SQLite database and classes, declared my columns, and I am trying to populate it with data from a csv file I imported in Pandas and converted into a dictionary.

I then used *MetaData* from SQLAlchemy to reflect the tables, and I'm then saving the reference to the 'measurement' and 'station' tables into their own respective table variable. Finally I insert the data into the tables, however, when I fetch the first five values of my inserted data (to make sure the insert worked), I get nothing. I'm perplexed, what I am missing or doing wrong?

```
# Dependencies and boilerplate
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import Column, Float, Integer, String, Text
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, inspect, func, MetaData

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///Resources/hawaii.sqlite")

conn = engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()

class Measurement(Base):
    __tablename__ = "measurement"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    station = Column(Text)
    date = Column(Text)
    prcp = Column(Float) 
    tobs = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"id={self.id}, name={self.name}"


class Station(Base):
    __tablename__ = "station"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    station = Column(Text)
    name = Column(Text)
    latitude = Column(Float)
    longitude = Column(Float)
    elevation = Column(Float)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"id={self.id}, name={self.name}"

# Create a "Metadata" Layer That Abstracts our SQL Database
# ----------------------------------
Base.metadata.tables # Right now, this table only exists in python and not in the actual database

Base.metadata.create_all(engine) # Create the 2 tables within the database

# csv to df to dict.
cm_df = "resources/clean_measurements.csv"
cs_df = "resources/clean_stations.csv"
cm_df = pd.read_csv(cm_df)
cs_df = pd.read_csv(cs_df)

cm_df=cm_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)
cs_df=cs_df.drop(['Unnamed: 0'], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

cm_dic = cm_df.to_dict(orient='records')
cs_dic = cs_df.to_dict(orient='records')

# Use MetaData from SQLAlchemy to reflect the tables
metadata = MetaData(bind=engine)
metadata.reflect()

# Populate SQLITE Table for Measurement_df
m_table = sqlalchemy.Table('measurement', metadata, autoload=True)
conn.execute(m_table.delete())
conn.execute(m_table.insert(), cm_dic)

# Populate SQLITE Table for stations_df
s_table= sqlalchemy.Table('station', metadata, autoload=True)
conn.execute(s_table.delete())
conn.execute(s_table.insert(), cs_dic)

conn.execute("select * from measurement Limit 5").fetchall()
>>> [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
conn.execute("select * from station limit 5").fetchall()
>>> [(1,), (2,), (3,), (4,), (5,)]
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you first use Declarative to define your models etc., but then create entirely separate MetaData and reflect (pretty much) the same info?

Comment: This is within the context of learning SQLAlchemy, the redundancy here serves to demonstrate how SQL's tables are structured by manually declaring the tables and associated columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly your action queries are not committing. Per [SQLAlchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit) in ORM contexts:

> The “autocommit” feature is only in effect when no Transaction has
>   otherwise been declared. This means the feature is not generally used
>   with the ORM, as the Session object by default always maintains an
>   ongoing Transaction.

Consider running [transactions in a context manager](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#using-transactions) which handles commits and rollbacks.

```
...

with engine.begin() as cn:
   cn.execute(m_table.delete())
   cn.execute(m_table.insert(), cm_dic)

...

with engine.begin() as cn:
   cn.execute(s_table.delete())
   cn.execute(s_table.insert(), cs_dic)

...
engine.execute("select * from measurement Limit 5")

engine.execute("select * from station limit 5")
```

Comment: Merci M. Parfait! I tried your solution but the output was the same. I did solve my issue: I deleted my SQLite Database manually in my directory, cleared my outputs and re-ran my script...I believe you were right stating that my queries were not committing...I just don't know why exactly...sorry for not being very insightful, I new to SQLAlchemy and ORMs.